# How to draw a curve in A-frame?

Tags: curve, aframe

I'm getting started with A-Frame and this is a very basic question. I checked a number of examples to draw a line and then a curve in A-Frame but they don't show up in the scene. I have a plane there that shows up correctly.

I can use `document.querySelector('a-plane').object3D;` to get the plane but `document.querySelector('a-curve').object3D;` returns undefined.

Here is a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A-frame room</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4">   </a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ffffff"></a-sky>
        <a-curve type="CatmullRom" curve="closed:true" visible="true">
            <a-curve-point id="checkpoint1" position="0 0 -4" visible="true"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point id="checkpoint2" position="0 10 -4" visible="true"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point id="checkpoint3" position="0 10 -8" visible="true"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point id="checkpoint4" position="0 0 -8" visible="true"></a-curve-point>
        </a-curve>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the JS component that provides `<a-curve>`. It's a community component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-curve-component

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. I opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/protyze/aframe-curve-component/issues/1) as even the example provided on the page fails to run.

Comment: Also as a suggestion I think `curve` and `line` objects are good to be part of the core library and providing some hello world example can be helpful. I can see Line component in the editor but couldn't figure out how to add it to my code. Cheers.